# Icons in Desktop

Tags: icons, .desktop

I've read some threads about this subject but I think none addresses my case.
I think it happened after trying to run a Phyton script as super user.
Now if I put an icon in the desktop I don't see it. It seems to me that it is there but in a screen region outside the visible range. I say this because if I put many icons in the desktop some are shown.
So, my question is how can I config the desktop so all it's area is visible.
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
Thanks in advance,
Luis Vital

Comment: These icon files are visible in `/home/$USER/Desktop`?

Comment: I have a similar problem - they're there in ~/Desktop, but I can't see them. However, when I shut down, I can see it. I think it is a problem with having multiple workspaces. As alternatives, you might consider using a launcher like Synapse, which I find easier to access and faster. It also has great plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and Type `sudo gksu nautilus cd ~/Desktop` now press from keyboard (Ctrl + H), now you can see, hidden file after you hit again (Ctrl + H) it's may hidden